# Summarize value counts per value in 1 column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

**Data:**

```
name | car color
-----+---------
mike | green
mike | blue
mike | red
bob  | green
bob  | red
tom  | blue
```

Desired result:

```
name | green count | blue count | red count
-----+-------------+------------+---------
mike |      1      |      1     |    1
bob  |      1      |      0     |    1
tom  |      0      |      1     |    0
```

I was thinking about running several subqueries and left joining such as:

```
select name, count(*) as count blue
from table
where car color = 'blue'
```

etc

Thank you

Comment: Do you know all possible colors at design time?

Comment: I typically run a distinct prior.

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN car_color = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) green_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN car_color = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blue_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN car_color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) red_count
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the colors at design time, you can use a pivot.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    personName NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    carColor NVARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @t
(
    personName,
    carColor
)
VALUES
('mike', 'green'),
('mike', 'blue'),
('mike', 'red'),
('bob', 'green'),
('bob', 'red'),
('tom', 'blue');

SELECT t.personName,
       t.red,
       t.blue,
       t.green
FROM
(
    SELECT pvt.*
    FROM @t t
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(carColor)
            FOR carColor IN ([green], [blue], [red])
        ) pvt
) AS t;
```

Output:

```
bob     1   0   1
mike    1   1   1
tom     0   1   0
```